# How to delete a page template created from the editor?

Tags: block-editor, page-template

I was experimenting and tried creating a page template from the page editor by clicking the button below.

[image]

I no longer want that template there, as I'm just going to do it the old-fashioned way and manually create a template to upload to my FTP instead.

I cannot figure out how to remove the template from this drop down menu below.

[image]

As you can see, there is no template in my site files (child theme), so I have no idea where this lives or how to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Appearance > Editor in the Dashboard menu, then in the sidebar select Templates > your template and you can delete it from the triple dot menu.

[image: The Delete Template option]